# Blinding a paper : the acknowledgements section

Tags: soft-question, st.statistics, mathematical-writing, journals

I am about to submit a paper (my first!) to a journal in statistics. There is a requirement to submit a "blinded" version. Should I remove the acknowledgements section too for this? If I do, what are the chances that my paper will be sent to the person whom I acknowledged in my paper? How do I prevent it?

Comment: 1) Well, the referee doesn't need to check the 'thankyous' for correctness etc... But this might be something that your supervisor (or equivalent) can better answer. 2) Depends... 3) You, as the author, don't have any say in the choice of referee. 

Comment: I have never seen it but why not just put 'I would like to thank ***** for their patience etc... and to the uUniversity of **** for their financial assistence.' Then it is clear that you are paying attention to the journal's policy on blind evaluation whilst making it clear that you are acknowledging help.  The editor is not going to send it to somewhere that is very closely associated to the university where you are. if you are concerned, mention this in your letter submitting the article. 

Comment: continued:
Above all don't worry too much about it as if the editor finds something that infringes the blind refereeing rule you will be asked to remove it.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that they would not send it a place that would be "obvious"; rather the whole problem was that the person is completely unrelated.
I really appreciate how you guys have helped me!

Comment: If you mention N.N in your article, chances are that he is the first choice as a referee. If you don't want this to happen, you should say so in your submission letter. 

Comment: Is that really so? Strikes me as rather unusual.

Comment: isnt there a bias in such a decision?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly Franz means by this, but if you acknowledge the help of someone, then I could imagine two completely opposite reactions by the editor. If they perceive that the person you are thanking is not closely associated with you but an expert in the area, then that would make them a natural choice for refereeing. On the other hand if the editor perceives that the person you are thanking is close to you either geographically (say same department), or by association (say advisor-type), then I doubt that they would ask them to referee. (cont'd)


Comment: At the same time, if your paper cites 5 papers of a single author, then that person goes high on the editor's list of potential referees. Then the editor might try to figure out whether this person is related to you or just ask them. I was once asked to referee the first paper = Ph.D. thesis of one of my students. I recused myself as I don't think an advisor should decide whether the first paper of their student should appear in a particular journal. This actually brings me to my point: As Tim said, don't worry about it too much. You can hardly influence the editor's decision. (cont'd)

Comment: If someone too close to you is asked they should recuse themselves and if they do, at the end the paper would end up with an appropriate referee.

Comment: Hmmm, this really helps. The person is not in the field of the paper, but comes in via one of the functions that I use in a new context. Thanks anyways. I guess I'll just leave it to the ed!

Comment: Should you do this, how do you prevent that --- while I think these are reasonable MO questions it really seems like the only opinion that matters is the editor's, and you should ask him/her.

Comment: I disagree with David Roberts's statement that "you, as author, don't have any say in the choice of referee."  An author can write to the editor that a particular person (or even a few particular people) should not be chosen to referee the paper; if that request is accompanied by a legitimate reason, I think the editor would respect it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about academia.

Comment: In the mean time, the academia.stackexchange.com site has been set up and a version of this question has been answered there: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/add-acknowledgments-and-self-citations-to-paper-only-after-the-blind-review